# App not supported by Nexus 5 on Google PlayStore

Tags: android

I uploaded an app on the Google playstore and it says that Nexus 5 is unsupported. 
Here is my list of user's permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
com.myapp.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.myapp.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE
```

Features:

```
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does your application ? what are the error logs ?

Comment: Do they not give you a reason?

Comment: I can install the app on Nexus 5 manually, but when I uploaded it to Google play, Nexus 5 got filtered out as unsupported device. 

No, it doesn't give me any reason.

Comment: Have you specified the min, target and max API level?

Comment: Yes, 
min -> 12
target -> 19

Comment: show your whole manifest file

Comment: Please share your menifest file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with the Nexus 5's screen resolution.

Try adding:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

To your manifest file. by setting `anyDensity` to true, you should solve your problem.

Optionally, add all possible screen sizes & resolutions to your manifest:

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
   <screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: <Screen android:screenDensity"480" android:screenSize="$screenSize"/>
I just need to swap xxhdpi with 480, otherwise it works for me. 
Thanks!!

Comment: [quote]<screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />[/quote] It appears the error in this line "android:creenDensity="xxhdpi"".error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi').